# Game theory IESDS game solver

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, game-theory

Okay so I am creating a program in Java that should take in a standard input that

```
1
2
3 3
3 1 0 1 0 0 
1 1 1 1 5 0
0 1 4 1 0 0
```

Where the first number represents that IESDS must be performed, second input (2) represents number of players and the 3 3 represents the number of actions per player respectively. The matrix below is the payoff matrix.

I am really stuck on how to go through the matrix and determine which action should be deleted based on pure or mixed strictly dominating strategies. I can't figure out a way to traverse the 2d matrix and compare player 1's rows with each other, and player 2's columns with each other. I know the first elimination should be the last column

```
0 0
5 0
0 0
```

the 3rd acton for player 2. Leaving the matrix below for the next iteration:

```
3 1 0 1 
1 1 1 1 
0 1 4 1
```

Comment: Sorry should mention it is perform Iterative Elimination of strictly dominated strategies on the given matrix. I have all the input correctly stored I just can't seem to figure out how to manipulate the 2d array

Comment: Essentially how would I compare 1 column values to the other columns in the matrix and 1 row to the other rows in the matrix and so on.

Comment: It's the most, wonderful tiiiime of the yeeeeear! [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)